Can we say "on a dictionary" instead of "in a dictionary" when talking about an online dictionary?
Normally we would use "in" before the word "dictionary" as in

"I found that word in a dictionary."

How about when we are talking about a web dictionary? It doesn't ruffle my ears to use "on":

"I found that word on a dictionary"

instead if we are talking about an online dictionary since we use "on" when talking about a website like in

"I searched it on Google."

I am asking this because one of the users here warned me once about using "in" in a case when I used "on" with "dictionary."

while I agree w/ the answers that "in a dictionary" is better, there's a lot of cases (particularly with the internet) where the prepositions aren't clear cut, and in those cases nobody will be confused if you say the "wrong" one

E.g. "I found that word in/on the OED" both are equally fine if you mean specifically the OED website.

I found this half-eaten sandwich on a dictionary. I found the word sandwich in this online dictionary

@Kaia Thank you all for the answers. I thought it would probably be so too, Kaia.

It doesn't matter whether the dictionary is online or not, the word is still in the dictionary.
The use of prepositions in English is complicated and often confusing, but a good rule is that something is in a text or written work (in a story, in a newspaper, etc.), and on a method of communication or a location (on television, on a website).
So you can say that the word is in a dictionary on the internet, but not "on a dictionary".

You can say you found the word "on a dictionary website", but not "on a dictionary" unless you're talking about something physically on top of a book that happens to be a dictionary.
"I found the cat on the dictionary".
"I found 'cat' in the dictionary".
You (generally) ride 'in' a car or aircraft and 'on' a train. Using the wrong term for the first two conjures up a vison of sitting on the hood or wing walking. In the case of a train it just sounds a little odd. If you need to express riding on top of a train you need more words. I'm not sure there is a general rule that covers all situations satisfactorily.
